# Playing Multiple wav files simultaneously

Tags: c#, wav

I have to play 5-10 wav files together.In my application, When any camera(each camera has a different wav file to play as alarm on motion detection) detects a motion an alarm(wav) file is played.
when multiple cameras (5-10) gets motion detection simultaneously then there we have to play multiple alarms(wav files) which are different for each camera.If I am using WMPlayer then the alarms are getting interrupted and also the whole wave is not getting played.

code for WMPlayer

```
var player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
                ////player.settings.rate = .5; //slow
                player.URL = soundfilepath;
                player.controls.play();
```

I also tried Windows API but it pauses my application(cameras) during which the alarm is getting played

Code for Windows API

```
PlaySound(soundfilepath, IntPtr.Zero, SoundFlags.SND_FILENAME | SoundFlags.SND_SYNC);

public enum SoundFlags : int
    {
        SND_SYNC = 0x0000,  // play synchronously (default) 
        SND_ASYNC = 0x0001,  // play asynchronously 
        SND_NODEFAULT = 0x0002,  // silence (!default) if sound not found 
        SND_MEMORY = 0x0004,  // pszSound points to a memory file
        SND_LOOP = 0x0008,  // loop the sound until next sndPlaySound 
        SND_NOSTOP = 0x0010,  // don't stop any currently playing sound 
        SND_NOWAIT = 0x00002000, // don't wait if the driver is busy 
        SND_ALIAS = 0x00010000, // name is a registry alias 
        SND_ALIAS_ID = 0x00110000, // alias is a predefined ID
        SND_FILENAME = 0x00020000, // name is file name 
        SND_RESOURCE = 0x00040004  // name is resource name or atom 
    }
```

Now My problem is how to play multiple wav files simultaneously without interruption?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried launching each play on its own thread?